# Angular 5 @Input always undefined on ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm working on an angular firebase app and I don't know how to solve a problem.
My @Input is always undefined on my ngOnInit() but I have to init something with this Input value.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I tried to add *ngIf as I saw in similar posts or to initialize my room but nothing is working. Do I have to use a timeout or is there a better way to do that ?

Here are the details:

players component:

```
@Input() room: Room;
    players: Player[];
    playersSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private playerService: PlayerService, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.playersSubscription = this.playerService.playersSubject.subscribe(
            (players: Player[]) => {
                this.players = players;
            }
        );

        this.playerService.getPlayersRoom(this.room.players);

        this.playerService.emitPlayers();

    }
```

html:

```
<div *ngIf="room">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let p of room.players">{{p}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
usernames:
<div *ngIf="players">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let player of players">
            {{player.username}} // This will not works
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

service:

```
    getPlayersRoom(ids: string[]) {

        while (ids.length > 0) {
            var id = ids.splice(0, 1)[0];
            firebase.database().ref('/users/').child(id).once('value', function (snapshot) {
                this.players.push(snapshot.val());
            });
        }
        this.emitPlayers();
}
```

room:

```
room: Room;

constructor(private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private roomService: RoomService
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.room = new Room();
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.roomService.getRoom(+id).then(
        (room: Room) => {
            this.room = room;
        }
    );
}
```

html:

```
<div *ngIf="room">
        Room n°{{room.id}} + password {{room.password}}
    <h1>PLAYERS room</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let p of room.players">
        {{p}}
    </div>
    Players:
    <app-players *ngIf="room" [room]="room"></app-players>
    end
</div>
```

Edit: 
The problem is in ngOnInit (players component): the @Input is undefined at this moment (and then it's doing getPlayersRoom(undefined) ). Any idea someone ? Impossible to use a @Input in constructor/ngoninit ? How should I do that then ?

Comment: Does the `Room` constructor instantiate the `players` property to an empty array? I'm asking, because the only location in your code where you use `length` is on the `room.players` array.

Comment: I think `this.room.players` is the problem. Not only you need to make sure `room` is populated, but also `room.players`. Your `ngIf` needs to apply to that, ex. `*ngIf="room?.players"`

Comment: Actually, you might want to work on `new Room()` to make sure `room.players` is an empty array upon init. I believe this might make your display layer robust. And you might be able to drop quite a bit `*ngIf`

Comment: Indeed, the problem is room.players, my room is an object (with id, players, password). There is something on room.players (but not at the ngoninit). The line <li *ngFor="let p of room.players">{{p}}</li>  is working for example.

Comment: Any idea guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution:

service:

```
getPlayersRoom(ids: string[]) {

        for(let i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
            this.getPlayer(ids[i]).then(
                (player: Player) => {
                    if(player){
                       this.players.push(player);
                    }
                }
            );

        }
        this.emitPlayers();
}
```

component:
I implemented OnChanges and then:

```
ngOnChanges(){

        if(Object.keys(this.room).length>0){
            this.playerService.getPlayersRoom(this.room.players);
        }
    }
```

I don't think that's the best way to do that but at least it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Gut response here, but it looks like your `roomService.getRoom(+id)` is asynchronous, which means depending on what happens when you initialize `new Room()`, that property may still be `undefined` by the time your child component is initialized.

Edit: on reflection, maybe you just need to declare your array properties as empty arrays up front:

`players: Player[] = []`

Comment: Interesting, so which line of code is actually throwing the error?

Comment: "<div *ngFor="let p of room.players">" or "while (ids.length > 0) {" (because ids = undefined)